# jasper reports table creation

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to create a table in my Jasper Report.
This could be done (and it is done :-) ) in iReport, but the content of the table (for example names of the columns) are changing, so I would like to create the report solely from JAVA code (by not using jrxml files).

How is it possible?

So far, this is what I have done (the main parts only):

```
//table component
final StandardTable table = new StandardTable();
final StandardColumn col1 = new StandardColumn();    
final DesignCell col1Header = new DesignCell();
final JRDesignStaticText textElement = new JRDesignStaticText();

col1Header.addElement(textElement);
col1.setDetailCell(col1Header);
table.addColumn(col1);

/datasource
final JRDesignDatasetParameter param = new JRDesignDatasetParameter();
param.setName("REPORT_DATA_SOURCE");
final JRDesignExpression exp = new JRDesignExpression("$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}");
param.setExpression(exp);

//datasetrun
final JRDesignDatasetRun drs = new JRDesignDatasetRun();
table.setDatasetRun(drs);
drs.addParameter( param );
```

How to continue?

Thank you,
krisy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon the same problem (and for future myself :-) ) here is how to continue the code above, to add a table element to the summary of the report:

```
//create reportElement (inside componentelement)
JRDesignComponentElement reportElem = new JRDesignComponentElement();
//reportElem.setKey("table");
reportElem.setComponentKey(new ComponentKey("http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components", "jr", "table"));
reportElem.setComponent(table);
reportElem.setHeight(100);
reportElem.setWidth(100);

//add to summary
jRSummary.addElement(reportElem);
```

(the hard part was to find out how to create the ComponentKey object)

Note: in order to use the table, the subdataset element needs to be created as well.

Comment: Could you please explain why you use "jr"?
I create HtmlComponent which the same as you i need to create componentKey. I get following error `No component manager found for name htmlComponent, namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent`

Answer (score 0):

For htmlComponent the ComponentKey should be:

new ComponentKey("http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent", "jr",
                "html");